# How do I change Empty Template to Internet Template in MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2012

A new MVC Web application has been created with Empty Razor Template. In this template I found that default controller,Model and View are missed. I need to change  the template from Empty to Internet Application.

I couldn't find any option in the properties to change Internet controller. How can I do that without creating a new project?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new project in reverse. Create a new project based on the Internet template, and use a compare tool (I rely heavily on BeyondCompare) to merge the Internet template differences into your existing project.

Comment: I just need an option to simply switch back empty to internet. Compare   doesn't work out.

Comment: That would be like switching a console application to be a windows forms application. There are project type GUIDs and the like in the *.*proj files that must be contended with.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between *Empty Razor Template* and *Internet Application Template* is in two (Account and Home) Controllers, Views that go with them and in different Site.css. You can't simply "switch" between templates.

You can go from *Internet Application* to *Empty*, if you delete Account and Home Controllers and corresponding Views. Other way around is a bit more difficult. Use [scaffolding](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/scaffold-your-aspnet-mvc-3-project-with-the-mvcscaffolding-package/) to accomplish that.

You can also check differences between templates [here](http://forums.asp.net/post/5463313.aspx).